Flutter Screen_utils to figma responsive problem
I am implementing a Figma design in Flutter using screen_utils to match the design exactly. The design dimensions are 430x932, but I’m encountering issues on smaller screens.
I tried solving this with FittedBox, but it caused visual inconsistencies. For example, buttons that have fixed sizes in the design end up with varying height values across pages.
Do you think trying to make the design responsive on smaller devices is unnecessary? Would it be a smart solution to simply use a SingleChildScrollView to handle the layout instead?
Thank you!
Image:

main:
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScreenUtilInit(
      designSize: const Size(430, 932),
      minTextAdapt: true,
      splitScreenMode: true,
      builder: (context, child) {
        return const MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          home: WelcomePage(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}



code:

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

class WelcomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const WelcomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<WelcomePage> createState() => _WelcomePageState();
}

class _WelcomePageState extends State<WelcomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.w),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 36.h,
              ),
              Center(
                child: Image.asset(
                  "assets/images/logo.png",
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 48.5.h,
              ),
              Column(
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "Let's Get Started!",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 32.sp,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                      color: Colors.black,
                      height: 1.6,
                      fontFamily: "Urbanist",
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 12.h,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "Let's dive in into your account",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18.sp,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      color: Colors.black,
                      height: 1.6,
                      letterSpacing: .2,
                      fontFamily: "Urbanist",
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 48.5.h,
              ),
              Column(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 58.h,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.r),
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: [
                          Image.asset("assets/images/google.png"),
                          const SizedBox(width: 8),
                          Expanded(
                              child: Text(
                            "Continue with Google",
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 16.sp,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: Colors.black,
                              height: 1.6,
                              letterSpacing: .2,
                              fontFamily: "Urbanist",
                            ),
                          )), // Metin
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20.h,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 58.h,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.r),
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: [
                          Image.asset("assets/images/apple.png"),
                          const SizedBox(width: 8),
                          Expanded(
                              child: Text(
                            "Continue with Apple",
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 16.sp,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: Colors.black,
                              height: 1.6,
                              letterSpacing: .2,
                              fontFamily: "Urbanist",
                            ),
                          )), // Metin
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20.h,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 58.h,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.r),
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: [
                          Image.asset("assets/images/facebook.png"),
                          const SizedBox(width: 8),
                          Expanded(
                              child: Text(
                            "Continue with Facebook",
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 16.sp,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: Colors.black,
                              height: 1.6,
                              letterSpacing: .2,
                              fontFamily: "Urbanist",
                            ),
                          )), // Metin
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20.h,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 58.h,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.r),
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: [
                          Image.asset("assets/images/twitter.png"),
                          const SizedBox(width: 8),
                          Expanded(
                              child: Text(
                            "Continue with Twitter",
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 16.sp,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: Colors.black,
                              height: 1.6,
                              letterSpacing: .2,
                              fontFamily: "Urbanist",
                            ),
                          )), // Metin
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 48.5.h,
              ),
              Column(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 58.h,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF369FFF),
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.r),
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: Text(
                        "Sign up",
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 16.sp,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          height: 1.6,
                          letterSpacing: .2,
                          fontFamily: "Urbanist",
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20.h,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 58.h,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFEFF7FF),
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.r),
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: Text(
                        "Sign in",
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 16.sp,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: const Color(0xFF369FFF),
                          height: 1.6,
                          letterSpacing: .2,
                          fontFamily: "Urbanist",
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 48.5.h,
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "Privacy Policy",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 14.sp,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      color: Colors.black,
                      height: 1.6,
                      letterSpacing: .2,
                      fontFamily: "Urbanist",
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    " - ",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 14.sp,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      color: Colors.black,
                      height: 1.6,
                      letterSpacing: .2,
                      fontFamily: "Urbanist",
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "Terms of Service",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 14.sp,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      color: Colors.black,
                      height: 1.6,
                      letterSpacing: .2,
                      fontFamily: "Urbanist",
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Sample Figma Design : https://www.figma.com/design/5SiXgaL0WrRYispa6vWboB/Untitled?node-id=0-1&m=dev&t=iIgwUW5v1zEkEU27-1

For responsiveness, I prefer responsive_framework, explore it too.
And in my opinion setting the limits is better so use of SingleChildScrollView is a good thing.

When I use responsive_framework, shouldn't I make a separate design for all device types? My priority is to do it that way if I can do it with one design. Do you have any advice on that?
